# Does Ubuntu Ship With Auto-updating Snaps?

Tags: ubuntu, software-updates, snap

I don't use snaps, but I'm aware that recent releases of Ubuntu ship with snap pre-installed. My understanding is that snaps are automatically updated, and that updating cannot be disabled. Am I correct in understanding that if I install Ubuntu (and likely many distros derived from Ubuntu), even if I'm not using snaps, there are pre-installed snap packages that will be forcefully updating?

Comment: [Yes](https://askubuntu.com/a/1040110/158442).

Comment: You can uninstall them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Ubuntu 18.04:

- Ubuntu Server does not come with any snaps preinstalled.
- Ubuntu Desktop comes with Calculator, Characters, System Logs and System Monitor installed as snaps. They autoupdate. You can uninstall them and install the traditional `.deb` versions.

For Ubuntu 20.04:

- Ubuntu Server comes with LXD installed as a snap. It of course autoupdates. The installer proposes a menu from where many supposedly useful snaps can be installed.
- Ubuntu Desktop comes with Ubuntu Software (the application) installed as a snap.

Comment: LXD are installed via snaps and they are very much server components that run web/DB servers, perform routing, etc. Spontaneous autorestart of those services may be destructive. I personally think deploying LXD via snaps is stupid, but it's a reality we have to face.

Comment: @oᴉɹǝɥɔ: Updated for 20.04.

Answer (score 4):

snaps will be updated automatically.

To check the status of the update use:

```
snap refresh --time
```

To configure the refresh timer:

```
sudo snap set system refresh.timer=From,To
```

e,g: To refresh the snaps 4 times per day:

```
sudo snap set core refresh.timer=0:00-24:00/4
```

Some examples on snapcraft docs , [Controlling refresh frequency](https://snapdocs.labix.org/system-options/87):

[Refreshing an installed snap](https://docs.snapcraft.io/getting-started/3876)

> Snaps are updated automatically. However, to manually check for updates, use the following command:

```
$ sudo snap refresh vlc
```

> The above will check the channel being tracked by the snap. If a newer version of the snap is available, it will be downloaded and installed.

You can update all snaps through :

```
sudo snap refresh
```

> there are pre-installed snap packages that will be forcefully updating?

Yes, the snapd will check for update even if you don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

Although `snap` is installed automatically, no snap packages are installed with a standard Ubuntu 18.04.1 Server install. I have checked:

```
$ sudo snap list
No snaps are installed yet. Try 'snap install hello-world'.
$ snap refresh --time
timer: 00:00~24:00/4
last: n/a
hold: 36 days ago, at 13:14 BST
next: n/a
```

So you won't have any forceful updates until you choose to install something that relies on snap.